# Is this a mistake in/by Resharper?

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper, automated-refactoring

I had this code:

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
bool grabNext;
foreach (string arg in args)
{
    if (arg == "-AA")
    {
        grabNext = true;
    }
    if (grabNext)
    {
        incomingPlatypusID = arg;
    }
}
```

...and Resharper suggested declaring "bool grabNext" in inner scope, so when I allowed it to, the code became:

```
string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

foreach (string arg in args)
{
    if (arg == "-AA") ;
    bool grabNext;
    {
        grabNext = true;
    }
    if (grabNext)
    {
        incomingPlatypusID = arg;
    }
}
```

...then, of course, I got an err msg, namely, "Empty control statement body"

### UPDATE

Actually, what I think I need is the following, as the "-AA" is my indication to grab the next arg:

```
foreach (string arg in args)
{
    if (arg == "-AA")
    {
        grabNext = true;
        continue;
    } 
    if (grabNext)
    {
        PlatypusID = arg;
        break;
    } 
}
```

### UPDATE 2

With this code Resharper does not complain:

```
private void AutoProvMainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    bool grabNext = false;

    foreach (string arg in args)
    {
        if (arg == "-AA")
        {
            grabNext = true;
            continue;
        } 
        if (grabNext)
        {
            PlatypusID = arg;
            break;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Was that made by ReSharper? `bool grabNext` should be *before* the if

Comment: Appears ReSharper didn't do anything besides "Find brace before this assignment and insert the declaration" (obviously ignoring the `if`). I'd say submit it to ReSharper's team.

Comment: Its simple to test. Write your code again, and see if re-sharper makes the exact same change. I think this was a fluke, but if you can RE-PRODUCE it (every developer should know that is important) then send re-sharper a video of your ability to re-produce the error and you found your self a bug. Congrats.

Comment: BTW, isn't there a logic error in your code? Shouldn't you have something like `else { grabNext = false; }`? Because, after the first true, all the others will be kept

Comment: @Andre: Good call; I need to break out of it once it's true.

Comment: @ClayShannon So you don't need that boolean after all. Simply test, get the id and break the loop

Comment: I can't get your original code to compile either.  `grabNext` isn't initialized before using.  We'll be able to be more helpful if you post exactly what your original code was, or at least a subset that causes the same error.

Comment: I'm guessing what you _actually_ want is the arg _after_ "-AA", not the string "-AA" itself  That would be easier to write `args[args.ToList().IndexOf("-AA") + 1]` or `args.SkipWhile(arg => arg != "-AA").Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @ClayShannon: Updated my answer according to your last edit. Use a `For`-loop instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Reshaper wants is something like this:

```
foreach (string arg in args)
{
    bool grabNext = (arg == "-AA");
    if (grabNext)
    {
        incomingPlatypusID = arg;
        // probably better break now:
        break;
    }
}
```

<sub>Note that the code always sets `incomingPlatypusID`  to `"-AA"` (if args contains it).</sub>

Increases readability and puts `grabNext` into the scope where it belongs to since it is used only there.

Here are more infos: [Scope of variables in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979493/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp)

Excerpt:

In C#, it's better to place them at the scope where they are needed.  This has a few benefits, including:

- You reduce the risk of error from reusing a variable inappropriately, especially during long term maintenance
- You are keeping the variable constrained within that scope, which eases refactoring

---

Note that the same statement could be even more readable using Linq:

```
incomingPlatypusID = args.FirstOrDefault(a => a == "-AA");
```

---

**Edit**: Update according to your modified question. Use a `for-loop` instead if you want to use indexer.

```
for( int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++ )
{
    if( args[i] == "-AA" && i+1 < args.Length )
    {
         incomingPlatypusID = args[ i+1 ];
         break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

with grabNext declared outside of the for each you could have the previous arg value of grabNext since it is only overridden if arg == "-AA".

GrabNext could be true from the previous iteration.